# When trying to call function it returns "attempt to call nil" , What did i miss? LUA

Tags: lua

### SOLVED

*What I learned:* Format the friggin code.

Error occurs at line 97 (which is literally just trying to execute sqr() )

A few days into learning my first programming language and I am lost as to why my function won't work. There shouldn't be any overshadowing local variables and to the extent of my 4 days of knowledge I've defined all variables. What did I miss?

This is the function that when called returns nil

```
function sqr()
 if Y < 3 then
  local  I = 5
 else
  local I = 9
 end
for i = 1 ,I do
 fd(I)
 altTurn()
end
end
```

sqr() returns nil and so does cube() which is likely cause by sqr() being called inside

This is the full program:

```
term.write("How high?")
 high = read()
term.write("How many runs?")
 runs = read()
Y = 0
x = 0
v = 0
function ht(y)
if y == 2 then
  Y = Y + 1
 else
  Y = Y - 1
end
 
function rf()
 turtle.select(1)
 turtle.refuel(2)
end
 
function fd(dis)
 for i = 1 ,dis do
 turtle.dig()
 turtle.forward()
 refuel()
 end
end
 
function turn(t,d)
 for i = 1,t do
 if d == 1 then
  turtle.turnLeft()
 else
  turtle.turnright()
 end
end
end
 
function altTurn()
  if x == 0 then
  for i = 1,2 do
   fd(1)
   turn(1,1)
  end
   x = 1
  else
  for i = 1,2 do
   fd(1)
   turn(1,2)
  end
   x = 0
  end
 x = 0
end
 
function sqr()
 if Y < 3 then
  local  I = 5
 else
  local I = 9
 end
for i = 1 ,I do
 fd(I)
 altTurn()
end
end
 
function cube()
repeat
 if Y <= 3 then
  for i = 1,3 do
   sqr()
   turtle.digUp()
   turtle.up()
   refuel()
   ht(2)
   end 
  else
   turn(1,2)
   fd(2)
   turn(1,2)
   fd(3)
   turn(2,2)
   rf()
   for i = 1 ,high-3 do
    sqr()
    turtle.digUp()
    turtle.up()
    rf()
    ht(2)
    v = v + 1
   end
  end
 until v == high-3
end
end
 
sqr()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing little formatting I have this:

```lua
term.write("How high?")
high = read()
term.write("How many runs?")
runs = read()

Y = 0
x = 0
v = 0

function ht(y)
    if y == 2 then
        Y = Y + 1
    else
        Y = Y - 1
    end
-- missing 'end' here I think
    function rf()
        turtle.select(1)
        turtle.refuel(2)
    end

    function fd(dis)
        for i = 1 ,dis do
            turtle.dig()
            turtle.forward()
            refuel()
        end
    end

    function turn(t,d)
        for i = 1,t do
            if d == 1 then
                turtle.turnLeft()
            else
                turtle.turnright()
            end
        end
    end

    function altTurn()
        if x == 0 then
            for i = 1,2 do
                fd(1)
                turn(1,1)
            end
            x = 1
        else
            for i = 1,2 do
                fd(1)
                turn(1,2)
            end
            x = 0
        end
        x = 0
    end

    function sqr()
        if Y < 3 then
            local  I = 5
        else
            local I = 9
        end
        for i = 1 ,I do
            fd(I)
            altTurn()
        end
    end

    function cube()
        repeat
            if Y <= 3 then
                for i = 1,3 do
                    sqr()
                    turtle.digUp()
                    turtle.up()
                    refuel()
                    ht(2)
                end
            else
                turn(1,2)
                fd(2)
                turn(1,2)
                fd(3)
                turn(2,2)
                rf()
                for i = 1 ,high-3 do
                    sqr()
                    turtle.digUp()
                    turtle.up()
                    rf()
                    ht(2)
                    v = v + 1
                end
            end
        until v == high-3
    end
end -- this 'end' close ht function

sqr()
```

Problem is 'sqr()' defined in 'ht' function.
**(Recomend)To fix this move last 'end' before 'function rf()'.** 
*Or. 

Call 'ht()' before 'sqr()'.*